# Simple Action bar using getSupportActionBar() - adding home < and settings icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I was wondering if it was possible to simply add a line of code to add the settings icon to my action bar. I have a few pages that have just a simple back button but would like to add another button to the bar. Is it possible? Or do I need to go through the whole process of menu items toolbars etc etc? Here is the code

Using AppCompatActivity

On Create:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Just trying to simplify things. I have made custom toolbars before where you would load the toolbar and the menu items. But was just wondering if you could do it through this as I just want an extra button :)

Comment: yes, you can do it simply, You don't need to work with `onOptionItemSelected`, use your custom back and other custom icons on the toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,it is possible.

Firstly you need to create a **setting.xml**

```
<item
android:id="@+id/setting"
android:title="@string/menu_setting_label"
android:icon="@drawable/setting"
android:showAsAction="always"
/>
```

Then override your `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.setting, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.setting:
              .... // your code
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: thank you simple and straight to the point, just what I needed!